# Mathematica Outline View?

Tags: front-end

**Edit** the question was reopened because the recipes linked don't work in version 13

Google Docs and [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), Jupyter notebook all support outline view. IE, you have sections/subsections on the left, and you can jump between sections in Mathematica. Is there a way to get this in Mathematica?

---

Example of what outline view looks like Google Docs

[image]

Comment: Also see the links give there such as  [NotebookOutlineMenu](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NotebookOutlineMenu)  **Create a dynamic menu that allows users to jump to specific sections in a notebook**

Comment: Outline view soujnds like what I need, but it doesn't work in latest (as of Aug 25) version of Mathematica